# Nginx, pass environment variables through to FPM automatically?

Tags: nginx, environment-variables

Is there any way when running nginx from command line to have all environment variables defined at execution automatically propagate to FPM?  Ideally without having to hard-code them in any config files?

I'm hoping to see if there's a solution that doesn't involve adding any tools, I'm aware of hacks/workarounds using sed, although my hope is to not add complexity.

Comment: This is not done by default for security reasons. You should very carefully consider whatever the problem is you're trying to solve; there is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: I could see that, although when running inside a docker container, the only env I have set are things pertaining to my hosting configuration.

Comment: The content of this article will help you. https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/50739cd498d2ae5d2075e25528bf8751